# Division circuit

Tags: arithmetic-division

On the picture below is shown a circuit for arithmetic division. Can somebody please tell me how does it work? I am struggling to understand it as I am new to this area.

Note:
This is not a homework or any school project, the ilustration is from my teacher's presentation, without any additional information how does it work, except that it is a division circuit. I have found a [site](http://www.softmath.com/tutorials-3/algebra-formulas/principles-of-computer.html), that has similar circuit with an example. But I think that I will better understand a text description of what is doing what.

[image]

Comment: Source of the illustration? (Hyperlink.) Is this homework? How much of it _do_ you understand? Put all the information **in the question** and not in the comments.

Comment: @transistor I have updated my question

Comment: @transistor I can read from the circuit that it contains an inverter, adder, mux and possibly a shift register for operand A. But the main information how does it work is unknown to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you understand how division operation works in binary , So I directly go for the explanation of the circuit .
We know that MSB(Most Significant Bit) contains the Remainder and LSB contains result.array below the register indicate that, left shifting operation occurs here.

[image]

inverting value of B and then +1 indicate that that's twos complement of B.This value is added with the A_msb of the register, so actually divisor is subtracted from the A_msb. if A_msb is not greater then B then carry is zero then output carry will have zero. So value of A_msb which is Pi will again assigned to A_msb. then then A register will shifted on bit of left and same operation will be followed again.if A_msb is greater then B , then carry become one and so , value of subtraction will be saved in A_msb and first bit of the register will be assigned 1. if value of our dividend is 4 bit, then shifting operation will be followed 4 times.